# Telegram bot in Talend open studio

Tags: java, telegram-bot, talend

Maybe someone came across this problem.
I try run my jar with telegram bot on talend studio, but my job just stop after start.
If i run job without Talend studio, just `java -jar TelegramBot.jar`, or I run in intellij idea, it's worked perfect.

I create routines and export my jar file in tLibraryLoad and in tJava call main method.

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultBotOptions;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.ApiContext;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException;

public class StartBot {

    public static void start() {

        ApiContextInitializer.init();

        DefaultBotOptions botOptions = ApiContext.getInstance(DefaultBotOptions.class);

        FMTelegramBOTTest bot = new FMTelegramBOTTest(botOptions);

        TelegramBotsApi apiBots = new TelegramBotsApi();

        try {
            apiBots.registerBot(bot);
        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("END");
    }


}
```

Work only this method

logs :

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 2607

[statistics] connected

END

[statistics] disconnected
```

[image]

Comment: How are you calling the jar in talend?

Comment: StartBot.start();
I have routines where routine = class from jar

Comment: Which component are you using?

Comment: I'm using tJava

Comment: Just want to understand, are you including the jar in routine or you are calling the jar directly in tJava?

Comment: Please provide the java syntax you are using to call the jar

Comment: I call method start from routine StartBot, my jar file i'm add in tLibraryLoad 
Just idk how i can run only jar file without routines. If u know how run only jar file, this is even better

Comment: My tJava contains only StartBot.start(); For start method from routines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using windows operating system, please use below command to call the jar file directly, no need to use tLibraryLoad component. This component can be used in case you are accessing any method from the jar. If you just want to execute the jar you can use below,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start path/to/jar/file_name.jar");
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! I try and it does not work. The result is the same. The feeling that talend does not keep the job running, but immediately completes it

Comment: And if i try run HelloWorld.jar where only System.out.println("Hello World"), it's not work too
My command : Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:/git/HelloWorld/out/artifacts/HelloWorld_jar/HelloWorld.jar");

Comment: I gave helloworld.jar as an example. And more over what are you expecting to do. What actually your jar file is doing?

Comment: Yeah, i just create a new project HelloWorld and try run it. My jar run TelegramBot, i need transfer him in talend for deploy on JobServer

Comment: Man, sorry! It's work, just logs don't show this. Thank you!

Comment: But how i can run this jar on Linux?